# negating rewrite rules for apache

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make it so that if the ending of a URL contains anything surrounding a number (except that the first part can be any combination of numbers, a hyphen or a p), then the url is redirected with whatever surrounding the number is taken off.

Here's my regex:

```
RewriteRule ^all/[^p^P^0-9^\-]+([0-9]+).*$ /allof/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If I tried these test URLs, the redirect should happen, but does not:

```
http://example.com/all/-a*1
http://example.com/all/plus100
```

If I tried this test URL, the redirect does not happen which is correct:

```
http://example.com/all/p1-100
```

If I tried these test URLs, the redirect happens, which is correct:

```
http://example.com/all/(100) - redirects to http://example.com/allof/100
http://example.com/all/minus100 - redirects to http://example.com/allof/100
```

Perhaps my regex is faulty. I tried removing the extra carets in the square brackets except for the first, and that didn't help, and I don't want to replace the square brackets with only a `.*` since I then won't be able to capture the number. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do, precisely? If possible, give a list of sample URLs before and after redirection.

Comment: In the URL, everything past the right-most slash must be only a number. Anything (that isn't a number) that is between the same slash and number must be removed. Anything (that isn't a number) that comes after the number must also be removed. I attempted to edit my question and the system would not let me.

Comment: You should show your expected output. For example, with `http://example.com/all/p1-100`, what is your expected output...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^all/(?!p\d*-)\D*(\d+) /allof/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gL8eM7/1)